# apollo-upload-client and graphene-django

Tags: file-upload, apollo-client, graphene-python

I have a question about using `apollo-upload-client` and `graphene-django`. [Here](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client/blob/01db5f8bb546d5339b4de57d2f41089a82fdd5c3/src/index.mjs#L55) I've discovered that `apollo-upload-client` adding `operations` to formData. But [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/blob/14dca8297d0106c85933c0cee9c535f176efd6fa/graphene_django/views.py#L289) `graphene-django` is only trying to get `query` parameter. And the question is, where and how it should be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the data that has a header like (when viewing the HTTP from Chrome tools):

`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="operations"`

and data like

`{"operationName":"MyMutation","variables":{"myData"....}, "query":"mutation MyMutation"...}`,

the graphene-python library interprets this and assembles it into a query for you, inserting the variables and removing the file data from the query.  If you are using Django, you can find all of the uploaded files in `info.context.FILES` when writing a mutation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution to support the latest apollo-upload-client (8.1). I recently had to revisit my Django code when I upgraded from apollo-upload-client 5.x to 8.x.  Hope this helps.

Sorry I'm using an older graphene-django but hopefully you can update the mutation syntax to the latest.

Upload scalar type (passthrough, basically):

```
class Upload(Scalar):
    '''A file upload'''

    @staticmethod
    def serialize(value):
        raise Exception('File upload cannot be serialized')

    @staticmethod
    def parse_literal(node):
        raise Exception('No such thing as a file upload literal')

    @staticmethod
    def parse_value(value):
        return value
```

My upload mutation:

```
class UploadImage(relay.ClientIDMutation):
    class Input:
        image = graphene.Field(Upload, required=True)

    success = graphene.Field(graphene.Boolean)

    @classmethod
    def mutate_and_get_payload(cls, input, context, info):
        with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp:
            for chunk in input['image'].chunks():
                tmp.write(chunk)
            image_file = tmp.name
        # do something with image_file
        return UploadImage(success=True)
```

The heavy lifting happens in a custom GraphQL view. Basically it injects the file object into the appropriate places in the variables map.

```
def maybe_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

class CustomGraphqlView(GraphQLView):
    def parse_request_json(self, json_string):
        try:
            request_json = json.loads(json_string)
            if self.batch:
                assert isinstance(request_json,
                                  list), ('Batch requests should receive a list, but received {}.').format(
                                      repr(request_json))
                assert len(request_json) > 0, ('Received an empty list in the batch request.')
            else:
                assert isinstance(request_json, dict), ('The received data is not a valid JSON query.')
            return request_json
        except AssertionError as e:
            raise HttpError(HttpResponseBadRequest(str(e)))
        except BaseException:
            logger.exception('Invalid JSON')
            raise HttpError(HttpResponseBadRequest('POST body sent invalid JSON.'))

    def parse_body(self, request):
        content_type = self.get_content_type(request)

        if content_type == 'application/graphql':
            return {'query': request.body.decode()}

        elif content_type == 'application/json':
            return self.parse_request_json(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        elif content_type in ['application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'multipart/form-data']:
            operations_json = request.POST.get('operations')
            map_json = request.POST.get('map')
            if operations_json and map_json:
                operations = self.parse_request_json(operations_json)
                map = self.parse_request_json(map_json)
                for file_id, f in request.FILES.items():
                    for name in map[file_id]:
                        segments = [maybe_int(s) for s in name.split('.')]
                        cur = operations
                        while len(segments) > 1:
                            cur = cur[segments.pop(0)]
                        cur[segments.pop(0)] = f
                logger.info('parse_body %s', operations)
                return operations
            else:
                return request.POST

        return {}
```